# Optional two-way binding on isolate scope for Angular Directive

Tags: binding, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, transclusion

## question

I just learned that you can have an optional 'reverse' or callback binding via:

```
scope: { parentScopeFunc: '&?' }
```

I'm trying to see if there is a way to do something similar with the 2-way binding.

```
scope: { optional2WayBoundProp: '=?' }
```

I tried with the link function's `element` & `attrs` params but then I lose the 2-way-binding back to the parent.  That method only allows for parent-to-child updates. Then I might as well just be using `@` scope mechanism.

#### edit

I found this question [Angular JS directive, change a 2 way data binding in the link function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665363/angular-js-directive-change-a-2-way-data-binding-in-the-link-function) so that answers the main question regarding `=?`.  However it doesn't solve the 'optional' non-bound value such as `true` or `false`.

## goals

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- write a panel directive that transcludes content and is collapsible aside from the header area:

  `<my-panel>
    <transcluded-header-content/>
    <button ng-click="toggleCollapse()"/>
    <transcluded-body-content ng-if="isExpanded"/>
  </my-panel>`
- in some cases I want to cache the collapsed state of the panel instance in a parent scope (hence the 2-way binding where the view's controller can determine how to cache this info):

  `<my-panel is-expanded="parentScopeProp">`
- in other cases, I may just want to declare it without binding to a parent scope property OR I may just not declare it at all in which case it assumes it's expanded.

  `<my-panel is-expanded="true/false">`

I understand that by using the `=` assignment, that expressions like `undefined`, `true` & `false` cannot be evaluated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`'=?'` is a valid scope assignment as of ng 1.2.x...

...as for the ability to have a means of interpolating an expression from an optional two-way-binding, that is still up for grabs.